# Using .index() function in nested lists

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that finds a certain value in a nested list, so I wrote this code:

```
list = [['S', 'T', 'U', 'T'], ['O', 'P', 'Q', 'R']]
```

However, when I inputted

```
list.index('O')
```

It gave me an error message saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
list.index('O')
ValueError: 'O' is not in list
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Very clearly worded.  I'm curious the best way to do this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it is really simple, `'O'` is not in the list, it only contains the other lists. Here is an example:

```
list_you_have = [['S', 'T', 'U', 'T'], ['O', 'P', 'Q', 'R']]
print list_you_have.index(['O','P','Q','R']) #outputs 1
```

Now if you do it like:

```
print list_you_have[1].index('O') # it outputs 0 because you're pointing to 
#list which acctualy contains that 'O' char.
```

Now a function for nested char search would be

```
def nested_find(list_to_search,char):
    for i, o in enumerate(list_to_search):
        if char in o:
            print "Char %s found at list %s at index %s" % (char, i, o.index(char))
```

Or maybe an even simpler solution as @zondo commented would be:

```
def nested_find(list_to_search,char):
    newlist = sum(list_to_search, [])
    if char in newlist:
        print "Char %s is at position %s" % (char, newlist.index(char))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem in one-line:

```
print item in reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, nestedlists)
```

Comment: You can use `sum(nestedlists, [])` instead of that long `reduce()` call.